Default value for highorder component in Gutenbrg?
I'm trying to add an additional setting to core/group component. Is there a way to add default value to
const withSidebarSelect = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
...

 const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;
        const { sectionType } = attributes;

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody
                        title={ __( 'Section' ) }
                    >
                        <RadioControl
                            label={ __( 'Section Type' ) }
                            selected={ sectionType }
                            options={ [
                                {
                                    label: __( 'Regular' ),
                                    value: 'regular'
                                },
                                {
                                    label: __( 'Header' ),
                                    value: 'header'
                                },
                                {
                                    label: __( 'CTA' ),
                                    value: 'cta'
                                },
                            ] }
                            onChange={ ( value ) => {
                                setAttributes( {
                                    sectionType: value,
                                } );
                            } }
                        />

I want RadioControl to select "regular" by default

The core Group block already supports background colours, with a predefined palette. You just need to declare support and your palette in theme.json.

Thanks — this is just an example, I have more options

you can set a palette to limit the background colours to just what you want, and do it without a Higher order component, but even if you couldn't do that, a block style would be a better option. I don't think this has anything to do with Higher Order Components other than coincidence, your issue is that you know how to set an attribute out of thin air but you've not told the block editor that core/group now has a new sectionBg etc attribute and what its default value should be. Fixing that is not something you do in a HOC, not unless white has an empty/null value instead of white

@TomJNowell so essentially you're saying that it's a bad idea to do that on HOC all together? SO I better use a custom block for this?
Please disregard the background option, I updated the code to be the "type" one.

generally patterns are better than block styles/variants are better than HOCs are better than custom blocks. Most of the time what people want to do can be achieved without writing custom code or with features already provided by core blocks and APIs. The cardinal sin the code in your question commits is assigning and reading attributes that don't exist and aren't registered to that block
